# Add field to OpportunityPartnersFrom object

Tags: opportunity

I want to add another field to the `OpportunityPartnersFrom` object (which is the the underlying object of the related list "Partners" in an opportunity).

However, unlike `OpportunityContactRole` (the underlying object for the related list "Contact Roles" in an opportunity) there does not seem to be any way to access the `OpportunityPartnersFrom` object in the object manager and modify it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some objects just can't be modified. this looks like one of them. I don't have Opportunity partners to test it, but if you can't get to it in setup then they don't allow you to update it.

This is all I could find on OpportunityPartner fields: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_OpportunityPartner.htm

Salesforce's API first hasn't been around the whole time so there are a lot of these older objects that just don't have the customization that newer things have.

Comment: I feared that's the case. Is it then possible to rebuild the whole `OpportunityPartner` obejct as a `CustomOpportunityPartner` and add the additional fields there?

Comment: Yes, it'll be just like any other custom object at that point. I had to do the same for opportunity contacts. That does not allow triggers so I made a custom object with similar fields and just pointed my users to that.